# How to use StructureMap from xml

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, structuremap

In my project I'm using StructureMap for DI and associations are set up in the web.config file like this:

```
<StructureMap MementoStyle="Attribute">
    <DefaultInstance PluggedType="CTRMModels.Models.Repository, CTRMModels" PluginType="CTRMModels.Models.IRepository, CTRMModels" Scope="HttpContext" />
    <DefaultInstance PluggedType="ActiveReports.Security.CtrmSecurityProvider, ActiveReports.Security" PluginType="ActiveReports.Server.Security.ISecurityProvider, ActiveReports.Server.Extensibility" Scope="HttpContext">
    <Property Name="connectionString" Value="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True;" />
</DefaultInstance>
```

The first setup works but the second doesn't. The CtrmSecurityProvider class' constructor looks like this:

```
public CtrmSecurityProvider( string connectionString ){...}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is some exception thrown or empty connection string passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested the solution is to format the xml like this:

```
<Instance PluggedType="ActiveReports.Services.SecurityTokenManager" PluginType="ActiveReports.Service.ISecurityTokenManager, Agiboo.ActiveReports.Web" Scope="HttpContext">
  <Properties>
    <!-- for the parameters of the constructor -->
    <Pair Key="reportServerUri" Value="http://localhost:8081" />
  </Properties>
</Instance>
```